# declare sql field value to aspx pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, activation

i have made a credit request page wherein users can request a value/amount. I have implemented that it should be activated first via email activation before putting the data to the admin page for viewing and approval.

i have made an "Activated" field where it is null until the user has clicked the link on his/her email address and it becomes "1" when user clicks it.
here is the code:

```
                            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            string constr = "Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security =True";
            string activationCode = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["ActivationCode"]) ? Request.QueryString["ActivationCode"] : Guid.Empty.ToString();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                SqlCommand Activate = new SqlCommand("SELECT UserId FROM CRActivation WHERE ActivationCode = @ActivationCode");
                Activate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActivationCode", activationCode);
                Activate.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                string storedUserId = Activate.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                con.Close();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM CRActivation WHERE ActivationCode = @ActivationCode"))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActivationCode", activationCode);
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        con.Open();
                        int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                        if (rowsAffected == 1)
                        {
                            SqlCommand userCmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE CreditRequests SET Activated = 1 WHERE ID = " + storedUserId);
                            userCmd.Connection = con;
                            con.Open();
                            userCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            con.Close();

                            ltMessage.Text = "Credit Request Submitted.";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ltMessage.Text = "Invalid Activation code.";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

what i want to happen is to carry over the "Activated" field and make an if statement that if it is 1, it will be shown in my gridview.

here is the gridview code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["IslandGasAdminFM"] != null)
        {
            bindgrid();
            Label1.Text = "- Finance Manager";
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Finance Manager credentials needed'); window.location.href='LogIn.aspx';</script>");
        }
    }
```

something like this:

```
if(Activated==1)
{
bindgrid();
}
```

any help or tricks will be of great help.

Comment: do you wnat to show a column in the grid if activated is true, or do you want to show/hide all data in the grid if activated is true/false?

Comment: if the link is clicked and activated == 1, data will be shown in the gridview. so far everything is working but i cant declare the if statement. if(Activated==1)

Comment: WHat do you mean by "can't delare"? Is activated always false? THrowing error? Please post the code you are currently trying to run that is failing.

Comment: no code yet sir. dont have any idea on how to declare the value of "Activated". im planning to have something like, if{"Activated"==1}, then bindgrid();

Comment: Ahh, OK. I think you should try to get some code going, and then come back if you're still having problems. We need to have questions that can be answered specifically. One note, though, if the value of "Activated" is in the database, you will need to get it from the database before you can use it.

Comment: any idea on how to get it from the database? @Jonathan

Comment: That's way too broad of a question. You might want to look into Entity Framework for a good way to work with database content in ASP.net applications